# Collecting values in array and pass it to php

Tags: javascript

I have these checkboxes with value in them that I would like to store and pass to php.
my function suppose to check each one of them and evaluate if thy're checked or not and then push/remove them from the array:

```
function isChecked(){
  let distributionEL = document.querySelector("[name='distribution']");
  console.log(distributionEL.value);
  sendingLists.forEach(function(list) {
    let sendSMSArr = distributionEL.value.split(',');
    if(list.checked == true){
      sendSMSArr.push(list.value);
    } else {
      let index = sendSMSArr.indexOf(list.value);
      if (index > -1) {
        sendSMSArr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  distributionEL.value = sendSMSArr.join(',');
 });
}
```

What happens now is that the function repeats the existing elements of the array and then adds the new value like so. let's say my array looks like this:

```
sendSMSarr = ['1','2']
```

and after if do .push to the new value '3':

```
sendSMSarr = ['1','2','1','2','3']
```

**I would like to store those values without duplicates.**

As for some other data in here:
isChecked() is invoked after the loading of the page and after every search. you can search for those checkboxes in a search bar. after every search the entire div is emptied `(div.innerHTML = '')` and then filled with the results.
then:

> // call func after every search
>
> listR.addEventListener('change', function(){
>     isChecked();
>   })

The distributionEL is an hidden input which I use to store the values I need in a string in order to pass it to php and later convert to array agian so I can loop through it.

sendinglist is all the checkboxes in my page `(document.querySelector(.checkboxes))`

**Manage to Isolate the problem:**

Each checkbox is added when checked and removed when unchecked separately but when I check a few together without unchecking the others its start to duplicate. Obviously I would like to be able to do that without unchecking

Comment: What is the specific problem and question?

Comment: As i mentioned. there are duplicate in the array that i would like to avoid...

Comment: Why are you resetting the value back in distributionEL?

Comment: I'm converting the array to a string and store it in distributionEL since in intend to collect this with php on submit and then use explode to convert it back to an arrayso i can loop through it

Comment: what does `distributionEL` look like ?

Comment: an hidden input

Comment: When and how `isChecked()` is invoked ? and what does `sendingLists` look like. ?

Comment: So if all you want is unique values it's easy to search how to return uniques from an array or not to push them if they already exist

Comment: beacuse apparently I can't fix this, I'm doing something wrong

Comment: why not listen on the change event i think of the checkboxes ? and have a global array that stores whether they're check or not accordingly.

Comment: because then I will have to loop through all of the input and add to each one "addEventListenr" insted of doing it once on the div that contains them